# In Windows, multiple CPUs can be triggered in parallel, but in Linux, only one CPU can be used

Tags: qgis, linux

When using QGIS, my environment is in docker (opensuse15.2)

Other answers are as follows:

Use this:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSettings, QThread

# parallel rendering

QSettings().setValue("/qgis/parallel_ rendering", True)

for use max cores



from qgis.core import QgsApplication

threadcount = QThread.idealThreadCount ()

QgsApplication.setMaxThreads (threadcount)
```

It doesn't work in Linux

Comment: Type:
lscpu
in the terminal and press ENTER.

What is the result?

Comment: "lscps" shows 48 CPUs,

I use "docker stats" to check the percentage of CPUs occupied by my image. Only use 100% (use one CPU)

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works